# Breaking of running lex program

Tags: lex

When I run any lex program it keeps on running. I need help regarding how to stop its execution.
How to break a running lex program? is there any shortcut key for stop running program?

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing Ctrl + C key... :)

Comment: yes. that always works for me. or ctrl-break if it's running on ms-windows.